Non-monotileable amenable groups
This is crossposted from MSE.
We say a subset $A$ of a group $G$ is a monotile for $G$ if $G$ is a disjoint union of right translates of $A$.
In his article Monotileable Amenable Groups, B. Weiss gives lots of examples of amenable groups which admit a left-Følner sequence of monotiles (e.g. profinite or solvable groups). Is there an example of a countable amenable group which is known not to have a left-Følner sequence of monotiles?

While waiting for experts to answer: I think the shapes of Følner sets for topological full groups of minimal subshifts aren't known in a very concrete sense, so maybe those?

I think that this question is still open. It is also not yet known whether all amenable groups are monotileable.
